# How to ask for user input while playing audio?

Tags: java, audio, input

I am trying to create a program that will play a audio file. During the time audio file is playing, a user will then start to give input (integers) and if the input is right, the audio will stop. For eg: audio will play and if user presses 5 during the audio playing then audio will stop. The problem I have below is that the audio will play and only after it stops will it ask for the input. Please help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("/Users/babe/Desktop/C1.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);

        clip.start();
        Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        int a = reader.nextInt();

        if (a ==5){
            clip.stop();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Research multi-threading. You will need to ask for the user input in a different thread.

Comment: The reason the program waits for the audio to stop playing is that you're calling Thread.sleep, which by definition waits for the amount of time specified.  If you don't want it to wait, don't sleep.